# Rails and Facebook connect API (graph)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am developing in Rails 3 and I need to use the Facebook connect API (Graph).
I am currently trying out the Javascript SDK and it works fine. The problem is I do not know how to "save" and interact with the information I extract in Rails.

The best thing would be to use some "native" Rails plugin for Facebook. I have looked a bit on the Facebooker Plugin but I do not know how to get started and use it.

Does anyone know how to interact with the Facebook API with Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to integrate some kind of server-side logic. For instance, you could use your own JS to call FB's JS and then AJAX submit the data received back from FB to your server for persistence.

Then, you could use something like [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) to make server side calls later to the OpenGraph API.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook `Graph API` is HTTP based, so it works with any language that has an HTTP library, such as cURL, urllib. Just call appropriate `url` with appropriate `data` and you will get you data as `JSON` object.You can use facebook [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) tool for sandbox testing of your api. For rails  [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem just makes it easy to call `API` and extract info from `response`.